# Swift3, How to add AnyObject in a dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift3

I had my files conveted to Swift3, one dictionary was like

```
var Detail: [String:[String:AnyObject]] = [
        "0":["0":["number":0,"imageName":"40"]],
        "1":["0":["number":1,"imageName":"3setting"],"1":["number":1,"imageName":"3private"],"2":["number":1,"imageName":"3currency"]],
        "2":["0":["number":1,"imageName":"3favourite"],"1":["number":1,"imageName":"3favourite"]],
        "3":["0":["number":1],"1":["number":1]],
        ]
```

I works perfectly in the past, but today it reminded

> Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal

But why it doesn't work now?
Why this happeded and how to solve it?

Comment: If your inner dictionaries have static keys, then you should model them as `struct`s instead. Also if the keys for your outer dictionaries should only ever be integers, then make them `Int`s instead – and if they're contiguous, then you'll be better off using an array instead. Overall, you probably want a `[[SomeStruct]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `[String:Any]` instead of `[String:AnyObject]` and you'll be fine.

As for "what happened": automatic bridging went away (e.g. between Int and NSNumber, or String and NSString). So a literal dictionary like `["imageName":"3setting"]` is inferred as a `[String:String]`, and cannot be assigned where a `[String:AnyObject]` is expected — because a String is *not* an AnyObject. But a String is certainly an Any, because *everything* is an Any.

You could alternatively work around this by writing `["number":1 as NSNumber, "imageName":"3setting" as NSString]` (because an NSNumber or an NSString *is* an AnyObject), but there seems little point in doing that here. In the general case, a dictionary is an `[AnyHashable:Any]` now, and you should use that as the catch-all type; AnyObject is basically going away, slowly but surely.